# Object graph relationship

Tags: ios, core-data, object-graph

Why isnt this working...?

I have a 'Client' entity and a 'Car' entity in a core data model. It is a one-to-many relationship. I have chosen a 'Client' from a table view controller and pushed a new table view controller which should display all Cars *that* Client owns.

Based on information in other answers in StackOverflow, I have compiled the following short code to kick out the name of the cars to display in the cells of the table view controller:

```
NSSet *cars = client.cars;
carsArray = [cars allObjects];
Car *car = (Car *)[carsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = [car carName];
```

However, this is not working. Can anyone see why? It compiles fine. FYI - 'client' is the chosen client object; carsArray is a NSArray declared within the viewcontroller header file and a Car has a attribute called 'carName'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What error are you getting &

Where are you calling this in the new "pushed view controller"? You need to create the carsArray before the tableView datasource methods set in.

Of course, make sure the passed entity of "client" is not nil.

THis could be in viewDidLoad or some initializer.

```
NSSet *cars = client.cars;
carsArray = [cars allObjects];
```

The following could be in cellForRow..

```
Car *car = (Car *)[carsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = [car carName];
```

Comment: Right...it was an idiotic mistake...I was returning 0 sections in my tableViewController. This code was indeed working. Apologies!